# How to stop users being auto logged out after about 3 or 4 hours

Tags: members, sessions, cookies, logout

Users of our site **( EE 2.9.2 )** are being randomly logged out after 3 or 4 hours.

I have checked cookie viewer in chrome and firefox, and **“exp_sessionid”** and **“exp_expiration”** are being set correctly and are not marked to expire in a matter of hours. They are set to expire **1 year in the future**.

In our login form we force remember me to checked and pass auto_logon=1 to the server.

My question is: **Is there some sort of idle timeout or weird config setting that needs to be overridden to fix this?**

> NOTE: This is on our members website , NOT the EE control panel. I know the control panel handles sessions differently and has an idle monitor. But the website shouldn’t be doing this.